# Find data-id which has got the maximum value

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I have 4 `data-id` attributes where all 4 text fields are optional. I want to get the `data-id` of the list item which has the maximum value and change the background color to `lime`.

I don't want to change smaller values. 
Sample values:(5-6-7-8), but I have 100 numbers like that.

```js
const input = [
  {q: "5"}, 
  {q: "6"},
  {q: "7"},
  {q: "8"}
];

input.forEach(({q}) => $(`[data-id$="${q}"]`).css("background", "lime"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="question-text" class="question">Whats your favorite colour?</div>
<ul class="answers" id="answers">
  <li data-id="5" class="answer">Blue</li>
  <li data-id="6" class="answer">Red</li>
  <li data-id="7" class="answer">Yellow</li>
  <li data-id="8" class="answer">Purple</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I am sorry, but I do not understand your question. Where are text fields in your code? What exactly in this example do you want to turn to green? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Looking at your code you are matching correctly. If I understand you correctly the data from your input matches all the data from the choices so of course they will all be green. If you want to test it, just change the data-id value of yellow to 100 instead of 7 and then it wont be colored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly common "array max" problem, with a DOM application.  You can use [`Array.reduce()`<sup>Doc</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to find the max, like so:

```js
 maxData = $(".answers li[data-id]").get ().reduce ( (maxObj, crrntNode) => {
    var idVal   = parseInt ( $(crrntNode).data("id"), 10);
    if (idVal > maxObj.value) {
        maxObj.value  = idVal;
        maxObj.node   = crrntNode;
    }
    return maxObj;
  },
  {value: 0, node: null}
);
$("body").append (`<p>The highest data-id value was ${maxData.value}.</p>`)

$(maxData.node).css ("background", "lime");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="question-text" class="question">Whats your favorite colour?</div>
<ul class="answers" id="answers">
    <li data-id="5" class="answer">Blue</li>
    <li data-id="6" class="answer">Red</li>
    <li data-id="7" class="answer">Yellow</li>
    <li data-id="8" class="answer">Purple</li>
</ul>
```

---

Note the relationship between `data-` attributes and jQuery's `.data()` function.

Comment: Thanks you so much it working perfect but i have some problem my values not decimal values , i have hex values so not work full :( like that . what do u suggest to me ?
  { q: "1B"},
  { q: "1C"},
  { q: "1D"},
  { q: "1E"},

Comment: 1b = 27  1c=28  1d= 29  1e=30 hex and decimal values appearance

Comment: For hexadecimal, change the `parseInt` call to: `parseInt ( $(crrntNode).data("id"), 16);`.

Comment: You re perfect !

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var elArray = $(`[data-id]`).toArray(); 

    var maxId = Math.max.apply(null, elArray.map(value => { 
        return $(value).attr('data-id');
    }));

    $(`[data-id=${maxId}]`).css('background', 'lime');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="question-text" class="question">Whats your favorite colour?</div>
<ul class="answers" id="answers">
  <li data-id="5" class="answer">Blue</li>
  <li data-id="66" class="answer">Red</li>
  <li data-id="7" class="answer">Yellow</li>
  <li data-id="8" class="answer">Purple</li>
</ul>
```

If I understand you correctly, you want to set background to html element with maximum **data-id** attribute value. If so, you need to reproduce next steps.

1. You get all html elements with data-id attr and convert them to array.

   var elArray = $(`[data-id]`).toArray();
2. Get data-id max value of elArray.

**Math.max.apply**(context, arr) return the max value of *arr*.

**arr.map()** method creates a new array with the results of callback function on every element in array. In your case, return array of **data-id** values.

```
 var maxId = Math.max.apply(null, elArray.map(value => {
        return $(value).attr('data-id');
    }));
```

3. Set the background color to element with max data-id.

   $(`[data-id=${maxId}]`).css('background', 'lime');

Comment: Thanks you so much it working perfect but i have some problem my values not decimal values , i have hex values so not work full :( like that . what do u suggest to me ? 1B=27 1C=28 1D=29 1E=30 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your first order of business would obviously be to reduce the array of objects by their `q` value while converting the strings to actual numbers. After that you find the highest number via `Max.max`. No need to loop through the list items here. You could simply use a jQuery selector and interpolate the highest number in the data attribute:

```js
const input = [
  {q: "5"}, 
  {q: "6"},
  {q: "7"},
  {q: "8"}
];

const nums = input.reduce((prev, {q}) => {
  return [...prev, +q];
}, []);

const highestNum = Math.max(...nums);

$(`[data-id="${highestNum}"`).css('background-color', 'lime');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="question-text" class="question">Whats your favorite colour?</div>
<ul class="answers" id="answers">
  <li data-id="5" class="answer">Blue</li>
  <li data-id="6" class="answer">Red</li>
  <li data-id="7" class="answer">Yellow</li>
  <li data-id="8" class="answer">Purple</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much it working perfect but i have some problem my values not decimal values , i have hex values so not work full :( like that . what do u suggest to me ? 1B=27 1C=28 1D=29 1E=30 etc.

Comment: What are the numbers you're giving me and how to they correlate with your problem? I'm confused.